# ETL SSIS : Redirecting error rows to a seperate table

Tags: sql-server, etl, ssis

I am working on a package that contains a Source, about 80 lookups and 1 destination.

The data in the source table is not consistent enough and hence my package fails very often.

Is there a way by which I can transfer all the rows which are giving at the time of inserting them in destination table?

For eg. I have 5 rows in Source and out of which 1st and 4th will give error. Now the result should be that 2nd, 3rd and 5th should go in destination but 1st and 4th should be stored in some flat file or a db table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If its failing while inserting into destination then Redirect the error rows to a flat file or in a table

Comment: That's what I am asking? How do I do that?

Comment: This might help you http://sqlserver360.blogspot.in/2011/03/error-handling-in-ssis.html

Comment: If you need other ways of storing your error values other than flat files let me know

Comment: @praveen: Thanks for the link. Even I am not interested in Flat Files. What other options can I try?

Comment: Did you solve your problem @RajJayaswal?

Comment: Yes, I did but only with txt files.

Answer (score 9):

You can create a second `OLE DB Destination` and direct the red arrow from your `Data Conversion` task to this destination. Then choose Configure Error Output in your `Data Conversion` task and choose `Redirect row` as an option for all Errors/Truncations. Finish the new destination mapping and you're done: data that is correct should now go to your first destination (green arrow) and incorrect data should go to your second destination (red arrow).