# DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED with error code 0xC0202091 when loading flat file

Tags: ssis

I get an error message when I try run my `SSIS Package` the error is:

> [Flat File Source [1]] Error: The column delimiter for column "Column
>   8" was not found.
>
> [Flat File Source [1]] Error: An error occurred while skipping data
>   rows.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Flat File Source" (1) returned
>   error code 0xC0202091.  The component returned a failure code when the
>   pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code
>   is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline
>   stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this
>   with more information about the failure.

Most of the `csv` files load no problem but a handful of `csv` files don't and prior to that the package has been working fine for years.

Comment: As the error message says, there is usually more detailed information in the log about the error, as shown in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/674a1ce3-fe1b-4d14-81cb-ea235fbf8855/) for example. Can you show a similar amount of information for your error? And which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Please edit your question to add information, don't put it in the comments where it's difficult to read and easily overlooked. The error message suggests that the data in the source file is not correct (because a delimiter wasn't found). Have you looked into the source files and checked the data mentioned in the error? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628352/etl-ssis-redirecting-error-rows-to-a-seperate-table) might be useful if it isn't clear which rows are causing the problem.

Comment: When I got this it indicated the destination disk had run out of space.

Answer (score 23):

Encountered this error too, turned out that its skipping data rows because my CSV file has missing columns. Try checking if the columns in your file is correct.

Comment: In my case, it was only 1 column. The column was there but the name was different by 1 letter. The metadata won't match and cause the error. I found it because of this answer.

Answer (score 9):

Possible Scenario would be Multiple CSV Files doesn't have the same structure (Column names
)

Comment: This is a random encounter

Comment: Random * infinity

Answer (score 6):

Similar to user2545231's answer (can't comment based on reputation), I solved this by clicking Reset Columns in the connection manager for the file I was trying to import.

Answer (score 2):

I also came across the same error. Yet I got it resolved by checking the flat file sources. Make sure that there are no unnecessary spaces, verify delimiter used for eg: a comma,etc and also the data entry should be in sync with the first row. I hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible source for this error is if you've created your system with a new version of an incoming file and then go back to import older ones and find the error ... check that all the fields are there! I discovered that for a few days "back then" three fields were missing, causing this error.

Comment: hth Mike..What is this ?

Answer (score 0):

I found through our FTP configuration older files can hang in the SAN or the FTP and this can cause this error as well.  Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error when I am processing a file.

In my case, the problem is the expected delimiter is TAB whereas the file that I have received was a comma(,) delimited file.

When I have correct the input file format, it has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a task that involved reading files and skiping rows if a certain condition was true. The name of the column used in there was "Pxs" and the actual name in the files was "PXS". It is case sensitive, it couldn't find the column. Corrected to caps and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just deleted those data flow tasks, clean designer, recreated same.. mentioned error got resolved. Its Microsoft :(!

Answer (score 0):

-check the detail message that is next to that one
-check the columns: there might be difference between what you look in this file and that is it actually