# T- SQL Capture data Overflow errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Aim - To capture data overflow errors from source to destination tbls.

I've have a source table that is being dumped with data and column data type is varchar

While the destination table has specific column type like decimal (12, 5), or Int etc...

Is the anyway I can find all the rows that don't fit the spec and flag it so that they are not part of insert and hence not cause the script to fail..

MS-SQL 2008 R2

Comment: You should use SSIS for this type of thing. On the import step you can redirect any failed rows to another destination e.g. flat file or table that has a column definition of varchar etc. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628352/etl-ssis-redirecting-error-rows-to-a-seperate-table & this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166707.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can do it by checking whether the value in the column of `source table` is a number before inserting to the `destination table` using `ISNUMERIC` in SQL Server.

**SOURCE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #SOURCE(SCOL VARCHAR(300))

INSERT INTO #SOURCE      
SELECT 'ABC' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '121' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '-145.78' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '200,000'
UNION ALL
SELECT N'£100.20'
UNION ALL
SELECT '0E0'
UNION ALL
SELECT N'₤'
```

**DESTINATION TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #DESTINATION(DCOL NUMERIC(5,2))

-- Only the numeric values will be inserted and is Type-safe
INSERT INTO #DESTINATION
SELECT SCOL
FROM #SOURCE
WHERE ISNUMERIC(SCOL)=1

SELECT * FROM #DESTINATION
```

**EDIT :**

If `ISNUMERIC` doesn't satisfy the values in your column, create the below function and check the value in your column in `WHERE` clause. I got the function from [here](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.isReallyNumeric  
(  
    @num VARCHAR(64)  
)  
RETURNS BIT  
BEGIN  
    IF LEFT(@num, 1) = '-'  
        SET @num = SUBSTRING(@num, 2, LEN(@num))  

    DECLARE @pos TINYINT  

    SET @pos = 1 + LEN(@num) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@num))  

    RETURN CASE  
    WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', @num) = 0  
        AND @num NOT IN ('.', '-', '+', '^') 
        AND LEN(@num)>0  
        AND @num NOT LIKE '%-%' 
        AND  
        (  
            ((@pos = LEN(@num)+1)  
            OR @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @num))  
        )  
    THEN  
        1  
    ELSE  
    0  
    END  
END  
GO
```

And in the query to select and insert, use the above function

```
INSERT INTO #DESTINATION
SELECT SCOL
FROM #SOURCE
WHERE DBO.isReallyNumeric(SCOL)=1
```

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is not very reliable - it treats as numeric many non-numeric strings - see https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2011/01/13/isnumeric-broken-only-up-to-a-point/. Newer versions of SQL Server offer `TRY_PARSE`, but that's not availble in SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: I have updated with a replacement for ISNUMERIC. You can check now @Ed Harper